# Load a Image from an Url to an Image View

Tags: java, android, image, api, android-glide

I am developing an Android app for which I am working with an API.

The API is returning certain results such as an URL of an Image.

Since I have always been using Glide library to load offline and online images to an ImageView so for this also I am using the Glide Library.

But the problem this time is that sometimes the url which is returned through an API is not returning an Image file but is returning a normmal file only. I mean that if I paste that url in an web browser then the file which is being downloaded is not in an Image form but just in an file form. Hence when I try to use that url with the Glide library it is not working.

But after downloading if I change the extension of the file to an image extension then the file is being opened properly as an image.

Any help on how a url which is returning a general file can be used to show an image would be really helpful.

This is how I am using the Glide Library

```
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .load(GetImageUrl())
                .asBitmap()
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .into(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your file with added extension and load it using glide. It will works the same. Like if you are getting a file namely 123, before loading that image using glide just add 123 + ".jpg" or whatever extension is and load. It's that simple. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not downloading the file in the app. It is the Glide library which is handling that. I just gave a case in my question.

Comment: What's the main question then? What I did understand is when you don't provide extension image don't load up, but it does when u provide extension.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this is when I use a browser in my laptop. But when I am loading the Image in the device I am using the Glide Library which might or might not download the image to show it. Hence I do not have a control over the way the library shows the images.